# How to get Unix time Epoch in PHP

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

I want to get the Unix time for 01-01-1970. It can probably be done using strtotime etc., but i was wondering if theres an easier way to do it?

Comment: Easier than `strtotime`??? Like what? You only thinking about a date and PHP spitting it out? ;)

Comment: Yeah well strtotime("1970-01-01") gives me 7200 for example. It's not quite on the money (i guess). Plus it feels like it's really locale specific.

Comment: Have you tried adding `H:i:s`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
echo date('d-m-Y', 0); // outputs: 01-01-1970
```

The unix timestamp for 01-01-1970 is 0, but you already knew that, right?

Comment: Haha I think someone downvoted my answer because of its shameless vote-gathering nature. To anonymous downvoter: it's not the code that answers the question, it's the subsequent explanation. **It's a trick question. The answer is 0**. No PHP function is required to determine the timestamp of the unix epoch.

Comment: I think that same someone downvoted my question. But that's fair to be honest - shouldn't drink and SO.

Comment: @JHollanti Well at least you didn't drink and get on Facebook. Drunk SO has done less to harm my personal life than drunk social networking ;)

Comment: Good point, need to change FB password, logout and throw away the cookies.